# Page Block table UI Issue

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have create a dynamically add row into page block table. it's work fine.

[image]
all field are blank when i click the plus button . i want to maintain field value. Please help me out.

//------------VF code-------------------------------------

```
<apex:pageBlockSection id="IdPBSViaOneAssum" title="Assumption" 
    collapsible="false" columns="1">
    <apex:variable var="rowAssum" value="{!0}"  />                         
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!assumptionList}" var="a">  
        <apex:column headerValue="Remove" width="5%;">
            <apex:actionRegion >
                <apex:commandLink style="text-align:center;color:#c00;" 
                    value="Remove" action="{!delRowAssumption}" >
                    <apex:param value="{!rowAssum}" name="assumIndex" />
                </apex:commandLink>
            </apex:actionRegion>
            <apex:variable var="rowAssum" value="{!rowAssum+1}"/>
        </apex:column>                                             
        <apex:column headerValue="Assumption">
            <apex:inputField value="{!a.Assumption__c}" required="true" 
                style="width:90%;height:16px;"/>
        </apex:column>                
    </apex:pageBlockTable>                   
    <apex:actionRegion >
        <apex:commandButton value="+" action="{!addRowAssumption}" 
            reRender="IdPBSViaOneAssum" Status="IdStatus" 
            immediate="true" 
            style="font-size:15px;width:40px;float:right;" />
    </apex:actionRegion> 
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

//---------------------------Apex code-----------------------------

```
public List<ViaOne_Proposal_Assumption__c> assumptionList { get; set; }
public Integer rowAssum { get; set; }

public void addRowAssumption() {
    assumptionList.add( new ViaOne_Proposal_Assumption__c());
} 
public void delRowAssumption(){
    rowAssum = Integer.valueOf(apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('assumIndex'));
    assumptionList.remove(rowAssum);
}
```

Comment: Please provide more detail on what the problem is here e.g. what value do you want to appear when you click the plus button? Ir is the problem when you save the values?

Comment: make it public pagereference addRowAssumption(){ .... return null; }

Comment: Try using wrapper class instead of the list of ViaOne_Proposal_Assumption__c, I had faced this issue sometime back

Comment: It's work proper when i remove apex attribute rerendar. Thanks for your help.